# How do I properly get rid of the .backupmanager files on my Acer 7741z?

Tags: windows-7

On my Acer 7741z, I have over 3,000 Acer `.backupmanager` files to delete as per a post I just found on SuperUser.

However, do I have to delete each `.backupmanager` file one at a time or is there a way to delete all of them at once?